# Android Studio with Google Datastore trouble processing "javax/transaction/HeuristicCommitException.class"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-cloud-datastore

When I added to my module the Google Datastore library, I follow:
https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries
Just adding the line:

```
compile group: 'com.google.cloud', name: 'google-cloud-datastore', version: '0.9.4-beta'
```

Caused:

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files
>   copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE    File1:
>   C:\Users\Admin.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.codehaus.jackson\jackson-core-asl\1.9.11\e32303ef8bd18a5c9272780d49b81c95e05ddf43\jackson-core-asl-1.9.11.jar
>     File2:
>   C:\Users\Admin.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.inject\guice\4.0\f990a43d3725781b6db7cd0acf0a8b62dfd1649\guice-4.0.jar

I added:

```
 packagingOptions {
    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst  'META-INF/LICENSE'
     }
```

And got:

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files
>   copied in APK META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties   File1:
>   C:\Users\Admin.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.netty\netty-handler\4.1.6.Final\a24e92d67e467a3b97ff63642ab56637990685fd\netty-handler-4.1.6.Final.jar
>     File2:
>   C:\Users\Admin.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.netty\netty-codec-http\4.1.6.Final\ee6c65cb3f39f212241e9131dc05a837e776fd70\netty-codec-http-4.1.6.Final.jar
>     File3:
>   C:\Users\Admin.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.netty\netty-codec-socks\4.1.6.Final\4731b98ef9557de20fc4124b7fb12ed13b5910d9\netty-codec-socks-4.1.6.Final.jar
>     File4:
>   C:\Users\Admin.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.netty\netty-transport\4.1.6.Final\4cba91ad2711c13a063d480f01edf70aa3f9387d\netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar
>     File5:
>   C:\Users\Admin.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.netty\netty-common\4.1.6.Final\654e4d8e87bc442be5c1d82d0369a3885f7168ea\netty-common-4.1.6.Final.jar
>     File6:
>   C:\Users\Admin.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.netty\netty-codec\4.1.6.Final\86ce3c559af6759a0b991b9ad2faec20981e18e\netty-codec-4.1.6.Final.jar
>     File7:
>   C:\Users\Admin.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.netty\netty-resolver\4.1.6.Final\2a1c97445b6aa544cd029faa72abfb3f85e9957e\netty-resolver-4.1.6.Final.jar
>     File8:
>   C:\Users\Admin.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.netty\netty-buffer\4.1.6.Final\dc1a304ee7c448bfa241f60c41948db6f12b653b\netty-buffer-4.1.6.Final.jar
>     File9:
>   C:\Users\Admin.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.netty\netty-codec-http2\4.1.6.Final\3c7cf39825f8ec4e4da848b4e237b29257750cf3\netty-codec-http2-4.1.6.Final.jar
>     File10:
>   C:\Users\Admin.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.netty\netty-handler-proxy\4.1.6.Final\2028f80883012becbb54162d9ebb9017905aca38\netty-handler-proxy-4.1.6.Final.jar

I added:

```
pickFirst  'META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties'
```

And got:

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files
>   copied in APK META-INF/INDEX.LIST     File1:
>   C:\Users\Admin.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.cloud\google-cloud-datastore\0.7.0\6bae1bf31e4b04fc8148d9a5ae61da168c60effd\google-cloud-datastore-0.7.0.jar
>     File2:
>   C:\Users\Admin.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.netty\netty-transport\4.1.3.Final\2f17fe8c5c3b3f90908ed2d0649631a11beb3904\netty-transport-4.1.3.Final.jar
>     File3:
>   C:\Users\Admin.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.netty\netty-codec\4.1.3.Final\790174576b97ab75a4edafd320f9a964a5473cdb\netty-codec-4.1.3.Final.jar
>     File4:
>   C:\Users\Admin.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.netty\netty-codec-http\4.1.3.Final\62fdf3c43f2674a61ad761b3d164b34dbe76e6cc\netty-codec-http-4.1.3.Final.jar
>     File5:
>   C:\Users\Admin.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.netty\netty-handler\4.1.3.Final\fff45bdc544a4eeceb5b4c6e3e571627af9fdb6\netty-handler-4.1.3.Final.jar
>     File6:
>   C:\Users\Admin.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.netty\netty-buffer\4.1.3.Final\e507ffb52a1d134679ed244ff819a99e96782dc4\netty-buffer-4.1.3.Final.jar
>     File7:
>   C:\Users\Admin.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.netty\netty-resolver\4.1.3.Final\fe4ba2ed19e4e8667068e917665f5725ee0290ea\netty-resolver-4.1.3.Final.jar
>     File8:
>   C:\Users\Admin.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.cloud\google-cloud-core\0.7.0\f7a89624a25ad1414c775d295d0d02ee834e71d5\google-cloud-core-0.7.0.jar
>     File9:
>   C:\Users\Admin.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.netty\netty-codec-http2\4.1.3.Final\4e68c878d8ae6988eb3425d4fc2c8d3eea69ff39\netty-codec-http2-4.1.3.Final.jar
>     Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':shepherd_app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'

I added:

```
 pickFirst  'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
```

At this point the "Make Module" succeed.
But when trying to run I got the error:

> Error:trouble processing "javax/transaction/HeuristicCommitException.class": 
>   Error:Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*) 
>   Error:when not building a core library.
>   Error:This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
>   Error:in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as 
>   Error:Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
>   Error:core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
>   Error:going on.
>   Error:However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a
>   core Error:namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example, 
>   Error:from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most
>   Error:assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
>   Error:compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.
>   Error:It is also often of questionable legality.
>   Error:If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
>   Error:appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine
>   Error:distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use 
>   Error:the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.
>   Error:If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact 
>   Error:building an application, then be forewarned that your application 
>   Error:will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be 
>   Error:prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your
>   Error:application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating
>   Error:system. You will be to blame for this problem.
>   Error:If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a
>   Error:core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to
>   Error:repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into
>   Error:your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in 
>   Error:conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help
>   Error:you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then
>   Error:that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately 
>   Error:lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.
>   Error:1 error; aborting Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':shepherd_app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

Any ideas?

Comment: I replaced the line compile group: 'com.google.cloud', name: 'google-cloud-datastore', version: '0.9.4-beta'
with:
datastoreCompile (group: 'com.google.cloud', name: 'google-cloud-datastore', version: '1.2.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.json'
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}
And removed "pickFirst", "packagingOptions".
Now I'm getting:
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK project.properties with: "google-cloud-core-1.2.0.jar" and "google-cloud-datastore-1.2.0.jar".